# Replacing clip in java with FXGraphics2D (Java.awt)

Tags: java, javafx, awt, javafx-8

So I was working a FXGraphics2D application with java where you have a shape that gets clipped and you see a random generated background of colorful lines in the background. This all went fine, but then I wanted to add the feature to move the clip Shape with your mouse.

In this case to the place the mouse has clicked on the canvas, or is dragged. You don't have to be on the shape to drag FYI.

There is one problem it seems with removing the clip, or just clearing the canvas. Now since I'm quite new as you may see to FXGraphics2D, but me myself couldn't find it myself in documentation or anywhere on the internet.

Does anyone know how to fix the issue of either totally clearing the canvas, indepenetly from the clip, or replacing the clip in some way?

Thanks in advance!

The current state after some clicks:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPbqI.png
It seems to me that FXGraphics2D places the next clip behind the old ones.

The code I have so far;

**Draw**

```java
public void draw(FXGraphics2D graphics) {
        graphics.setTransform(new AffineTransform());
        graphics.setBackground(Color.white);
        graphics.clearRect(0, 0, (int)canvas.getWidth(), (int)canvas.getHeight());

        graphics.setPaint(Color.black);
        graphics.draw(clippingEllipse.getShape());
        graphics.clip(clippingEllipse.getShape());

        Set<Line> lineSet = Line.getLineSet(1000,1920,1080);
        for (Line line : lineSet){
            graphics.setPaint(line.getColor());
            graphics.drawLine(line.getX1(), line.getY1(), line.getX2(), line.getY2());
        }
    }
```

**Handle** (method call of setOnMousePressed() and setOnMouseDragged())

```java
private void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        this.clippingEllipse.setX((int) event.getX() - this.clippingEllipse.getWidth() / 2);
        this.clippingEllipse.setY((int) event.getY() - this.clippingEllipse.getWidth() / 2);
    }
```

**Start**

```java
        this.clippingEllipse = new ClippingEllipse(1920/2-100, 1080/2-100, 200);

        BorderPane mainPane = new BorderPane();
        canvas = new ResizableCanvas(g -> draw(g), mainPane);
        mainPane.setCenter(canvas);
        FXGraphics2D g2d = new FXGraphics2D(canvas.getGraphicsContext2D());

        new AnimationTimer() {
            long last = -1;
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
        if(last == -1)
                    last = now;
        update((now - last) / 1000000000.0);
        last = now;
        draw(g2d);
            }
        }.start();

        canvas.setOnMousePressed(event -> handle(event));

        canvas.setOnMouseDragged(event -> handle(event));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(mainPane));
        stage.setFullScreen(true);
        stage.setTitle("Spotlight");
        stage.show();
        draw(g2d);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came across for people interested;

`graphics.clip(clippingEllipse.getShape());`
to
`graphics.setClip(clippingEllipse.getShape());`

&

Add this in the end of the draw() method;
`graphics.clip(null);`

**edit:**
also an possibility: `graphics.setClip(null);`